# Matching all values in NOT IN clause

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to ensure all values in an NOT IN clause are matched?

Example:

I have a table DateValue with 2 columns Date and Value

```
ID========  DATE   ============VALUE
1========2015-01-01=========== 12
2========2015-01-01=========== 13
3========2015-01-01=========== 15
4========2015-01-01=========== 16
5========2015-01-02========== 15
6========2015-01-04=========== 15
7========2015-01-05=========== 16
8========2015-01-06=========== 12
9========2015-01-06=========== 13
10========2015-01-06=========== 15
```

How I select all row where VALUE not = 12, 13 and 15 in same day

=> That mean I will return:

```
5========2015-01-02========== 15
6========2015-01-04=========== 15
7========2015-01-05=========== 16
```

Comment: VALUE NOT IN (12,13,15);

Comment: Go on. Try something. Maybe start with something slightly simpler (like WHERE all values ARE matched)

Comment: It will return row have value not in 12, 13 or 15. I need it matching all values in NOT IN clause, friend :)

Comment: Yes, friend. I want select all the rows where VALUE is not 12 and not 13 and not 15 in same day. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `DateValue` 
WHERE `Date` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `Date`
    FROM `result` 
    WHERE VALUE IN (12,13,15)
)
```

Who have better solution (Don't use sub-query)?

Comment: This query doesn't run because the inner query returns rows having 3 columns and the outer query attempts to match `VALUE` (only one column) against them. Even if it runs, it doesn't return the result you are asking for. It should contain a condition on the day.

Comment: So sorry, Yes. You're right. I've just updated it :)

Answer (score 0):

In a first step you can find the dates when `VALUE` has all the values (`12`, `13` and `15`):

```
SELECT `DATE`
FROM DateValue
WHERE `VALUE` IN (12, 13, 15)
GROUP BY `DATE`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

You can use this as a subquery to get the values you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM DateValue
WHERE `DATE` NOT IN (
    SELECT `DATE`
    FROM DateValue
    WHERE `VALUE` IN (12, 13, 15)
    GROUP BY `DATE`
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) a
```

Comment: But I think don't need "GROUP BY `DATE`HAVING COUNT(*) = 3"